# How do i apply the wp_trim_words function only to H3 Title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display **first word of posts title** only on **frontpage** of my website.

**My Problem:** I have the below coding, but it does not apply to the posts title of frontpage, but it effect the website **menu title** and **blog main title**, while i want to target only posts title on my website frontpage.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_75691_trim_words' );

function wpse_75691_trim_words( $title )
{
    // Limit the title to exactly one word only on the frontpage.
    if (is_front_page()) {
        return wp_trim_words( $title, 1, '' );
    }
    // Otherwise return the full title.
    return $title; 
}
```

**What i want to do**:

- **1:** The above code should not apply to the menu title or blog title
- **2:** The above code should display only first word of post title on my frontpage.

My posts title on frontpage looks like this in inspect element:

[image]

**Hint:** I think, if the above code target only **h3 title**, then it will effect only the posts title and no other title tags on my frontpage. So, can anyone modify the coding to apply the function only to the post title and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

For trimming the title only for "post" title on the "front page", then you could do something like this:

```php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'your_them_custom_title', 10, 2 );

function your_them_custom_title( $title, $post_id ) 
{

  if( is_front_page() && 'post' === get_post_type( $post_id ) && !is_admin()  ) {

    return wp_trim_words( $title, 1, '' );
    
  }

  return $title;

}
```

And also if you want to keep the naviagtion menu title intact then you could do something like this:

```php
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_title', 'your_them_nav_title', 10, 4 );

function your_them_nav_title( $title, $item, $args, $depth )
{

  # Removing your custom title for the nav menu 
  remove_filter( 'the_title', 'your_them_custom_title', 10, 2 );

  $title   = get_the_title( $item->object_id );

  # Adding your custom title back 
  add_filter( 'the_title', 'your_them_custom_title', 10, 2 );

  return $title;

}
```

---

UPDATE:

If you're NOT sure which page you're referring to, then you can run this conditional check to see which page you need to check to run the `wp_trim_words` on.

"Copy/past" the following code to the `functions.php` to determine the right page you're referring to:

```php
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {

  echo "default index page which is also the front page";

} elseif ( is_front_page()){

  echo "custom front page";

} elseif ( is_home()){

echo "default index page";

} else {

echo "neither front nor blog index";

}
```

Comment: i have tested your first code and put it in function.php file but it is not working and not displaying the first word of the post title on homepage, check it yourself on the site copybloggerthemes.com if you see the first word of posts title i did it with Css3, So please modify the code so it start working for me to display first work with php not with css. Looking forward to you. thanks

Comment: All you need to do is to "copy/past" BOTH of snippets to your theme `funnctions.php`. I've tested the code on three different themes and THEY WORK SEAMLESSLY FINE! You first needed the code to run on the "front page" and you refer to that page as "homepage"! These two pages can mean different things in wordpress. Please clarify which one is it? IS IT A CUSTOM PAGE THAT YOU USE AS FRONT PAGE? OR IS IT THE DIFFAULT BLOG INDEX PAGE OF WORDPRESS?

Comment: I just updated my answer and provided a conditional check for you to "copy/past" to your theme ```functions.php``` to determine which page you're referring to!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't know which code should i past first and then second could you kindly combined the code to past in function.php correctly, I don't know which one to pick and to past properly. Hope to see you soon.

Comment: I am using Enfold theme Frontpage for my website homepage. I did not select anything from wordpress latest page setting but inside enfold it provides options to set the frontpage for your homepage.